# What is the boundary point of the set of all convergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

I'm not sure as to how to define this.
As in let $C$ be the set of all convergent sequence of real numbers.
Then what would a boundary point of $C$ be in $(l_\infty, d_\infty)$.?

Comment: (1) Sequences of what? (2) Convergent with respect to what topology? (3) Boundary with respect to what topology? (4) Open ball with respect to what metric (!) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C$ is its own boundary.

Any convergent sequence $(a_n)$ is in the boundary; for any "radius" $\varepsilon>0$, the sequence $(a_n+(-1)^n\varepsilon)$ does not converge, and has distance $\varepsilon$ from $(a_n)$.

Conversely, any non-convergent sequence $(a_n)$ is not in the boundary. Negating the definition of (Cauchy) convergence, there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that, no matter how far $N\in\mathbb N$ we go in the sequence, there exist indices $n,m>N$ with $|a_n-a_m|\geq\varepsilon$. Then, for any sequence $\lVert(b_n)\rVert<\frac14\varepsilon$,

$$|(a_n+b_n)-(a_m+b_m)|=|(a_n-a_m)+b_n-b_m|$$

$$\geq|a_n-a_m|-|b_n|-|b_m|$$

$$>\varepsilon-\tfrac14\varepsilon-\tfrac14\varepsilon$$

$$=\tfrac12\varepsilon$$

which shows that $(a_n+b_n)$ does not converge. In other words, anything in the ball of radius $\frac14\varepsilon$ around $(a_n)$ is also non-convergent.

Comment: Maybe a small remark can be  added why a non-convergent sequence cannot be a boundary point of C, showing that $C$ is closed on the given topology.

Comment: I interpreted the question as "find a boundary point", not "find all boundary points", but I will answer the latter now.